# How to authenticate the Api with JWT in Swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, jwt

I want to try the authentication web service using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) — that includes both client-side, and server-side code. and trying to fetch the access_token but I can't get the authentication even username and password is correct.

This is Login View and I enter the valid username and password:

```
struct LoginViewExample: View {

    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
//    @State var isAuthenticated: Bool = false

    @StateObject private var loginVM = DashBoardLoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{


            VStack() {
                Text("Welcome!")
                    .font(.title)
                   
             
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                    TextField("Username", text: $loginVM.username)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .padding()
                       

                    SecureField("Password", text: $loginVM.password)
                        .textContentType(.password)
                        .padding()
                       
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 50)
            

                Button(action: {
               
                    loginVM.login()

                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                     
                }.padding(.top, 50)

               
              
            }
            .background(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow, Color.green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
    }
    }
```

> This is struct  Auth Body Model

```
    struct LoginRequestBodyAuth: Codable {
        let username: String
        let password: String
    }
    struct LoginAuthResponse: Codable {
        let access_token: String? // this is access token key 
    
    }


class DashBoardLoginViewModel: ObservableObject {


    @Published var isAuthenticated: Bool = false

    var username: String = "8299544315" //this is valid username
    var password: String = "12345678" //this is password

    func login() {

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        AuthenticationService().login(username: username, password: password) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let token):
                    defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "access_token")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isAuthenticated = true
                        print(token)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)  //this prints every time
            }
        }
    }

   

       }
}
```

> This is Web service here I set the body and header. And don't understand where I am doing wrong. please correct me where I am wrong. this is my full approach.

```
class AuthenticationService {

    func login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "example url") else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
            return
        }

        let body = LoginRequestBodyAuth(username: username, password: password)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                return
            }

            try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginAuthResponse.self, from: data)

            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginAuthResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }

            guard let token = loginResponse.access_token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }

            completion(.success(token))

        }.resume()

    }


}
```

Comment: Changes that somebody will spot the relevant problem in this code is quite small (if it is in this code at all). Please create a minimal, reproducible example, or provide sufficient debugging information telling us exactly where the code takes an unexpected path or shows unexpected data. And please provide a better error description than "I can't get the authentication".

Comment: whenever I enter the right username ad password also gives  authentication failure message. I don't understand where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the response model(JSON) of this request. There can be multiple reasons, May be your response is not mapping on your model(May be different keys). Need more debugging info for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please Add the logout_consent for if u want to get the access if
> anyone is logged in. do this Approach. In my case this is working.

```
 struct LoginRequestBodyAuth: Codable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let logout_consent:String
}
```

> and some changes in Your AuthenticationService Class

```
class AuthenticationService {

    func login(username: String, password: String,completion: @escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "urlExample") else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
            return
        }

        let body = LoginRequestBodyAuth(email: username, password: password, logout_consent: "1")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                return
            }

            

            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginAuthResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
               // print(loginResponse)
            guard let token = loginResponse.access_token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }

            completion(.success(token))

        }.resume()

    }


}
```